# Neoload results details

Tags: httpresponse, neoload, test-results

Is there any possibility to view request wise response time rather than transaction wise based in neoload desktop version. Any automated view other than changing it to tree view and viewing all the transactions wise API's.

Tried searching in other blog I can get it in neoload web version but my problem is I want it in neoload desktop version.